# Why is my canvas line so small and disoriented?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

In my very simple code example below, I am trying to draw a box, 10 pixels in from the margin all the way around the outside of a canvas. Despite getting what seem like legit values from the screen extends of the browser window, I am only getting an L-shaped line, which seems really odd. My code seems very straight forward. So 2 questions:

- Why is it so small (eg not going across the whole browser window?
- Why isn't it a box like the code suggests it should be?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p id="X">X:</p>
<p id="Y">Y:</p>
<!--<form>
Timeline Item: <input type="text" name="item"><br>
Timeline Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
</form>-->
<canvas id="DemoCanvas" width=100% height=100%></canvas>  

<script>  

var canvas = document.getElementById('DemoCanvas');
var xoutput = document.getElementById('X');
var youtput = document.getElementById('Y');


// Always check for properties and methods, to make sure your code doesn't break in other browsers.
if (canvas.getContext) 
 {
  var margin = 10;

  var startx = margin;
  var starty = margin;

  var endx = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) - margin;
 var endy = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight) - margin;

 xoutput.innerHTML = endx;
 youtput.innerHTML = endy-margin;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   context.beginPath(); 

   context.moveTo(startx,starty);
   context.lineTo(endx,starty);
 context.lineTo(endx,endy);
  context.lineTo(startx,endy);
   context.lineTo(startx,starty);
  
  context.stroke();
 }
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the result which you can clearly see is both way too small and not a box at all:

[image: Resulting not-a-box]

Comment: Hint: Delete the every instance of `%` in your code, and notice that nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the common misunderstanding of the canvas' `height` and `width` properties. You're giving the values as percents, but that wont work. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement):

> HTMLCanvasElement.height Is a positive integer reflecting the height
>   HTML attribute of the  element interpreted in CSS pixels. When
>   the attribute is not specified, or if it is set to an invalid value,
>   like a negative, the default value of 150 is used.

So you should use plain integers instead. If you need a dynamic size, you can use javascript to update the values.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p id="X">X:</p>
<p id="Y">Y:</p>
<!--<form>
Timeline Item: <input type="text" name="item"><br>
Timeline Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
</form>-->
<canvas id="DemoCanvas" width="628" height="200"></canvas>  

<script>  

var canvas = document.getElementById('DemoCanvas');
var xoutput = document.getElementById('X');
var youtput = document.getElementById('Y');


// Always check for properties and methods, to make sure your code doesn't break in other browsers.
if (canvas.getContext) 
 {
  var margin = 10;

  var startx = margin;
  var starty = margin;

  var endx = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) - margin;
 var endy = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight) - margin;

 xoutput.innerHTML = endx;
 youtput.innerHTML = endy-margin;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   context.beginPath(); 

   context.moveTo(startx,starty);
   context.lineTo(endx,starty);
 context.lineTo(endx,endy);
  context.lineTo(startx,endy);
   context.lineTo(startx,starty);
  
  context.stroke();
 }
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did it. I'd love to know why exactly the height and width on this particular "canvas" element breaks with the standard of "100%" etc. I assume it's to enforce a manual redraw.

Comment: @screenglow I think the confusion comes from the fact that `width` and `height` properties used to be the proper way to set an element's size. Nowadays that's done with css, while a canvas element's `width` and `height` properties define the resolution of the drawing area.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using window / document width & height, 
e.g. the entire webpage, so the lines goes outside of the canvas.

you should instead use the canvas element's width & height.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('DemoCanvas');
var xoutput = document.getElementById('X');
var youtput = document.getElementById('Y');


// Always check for properties and methods, to make sure your code doesn't break in other browsers.
if (canvas.getContext) 
 {
  var margin = 10;

  var startx = margin;
  var starty = margin;

  var endx = canvas.clientWidth - margin;
 var endy = canvas.clientHeight - margin;

 xoutput.innerHTML = endx;
 youtput.innerHTML = endy-margin;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   context.beginPath(); 

   context.moveTo(startx,starty);
   context.lineTo(endx,starty);
 context.lineTo(endx,endy);
  context.lineTo(startx,endy);
   context.lineTo(startx,starty);
  
  context.stroke();
 }
```

```html
<p id="X">X:</p>
<p id="Y">Y:</p>
<!--<form>
Timeline Item: <input type="text" name="item"><br>
Timeline Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
</form>-->
<canvas id="DemoCanvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

To achieve "fullscreen", something you can do is to use a parent element or the body tag and then "copy" it's width & height to the canvas afterwards.
Note that i use vh & vw instead of % to avoid any stretching issues, etc.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('DemoCanvas');
var xoutput = document.getElementById('X');
var youtput = document.getElementById('Y');

updateCanvasSize();

function updateCanvasSize(){
  canvas.width = bodySim.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = bodySim.clientHeight;
  
  draw();
  }
 
function draw(){
 if (canvas.getContext) 
 {
  var margin = 10;

  var startx = margin;
  var starty = margin;

  var endx = canvas.clientWidth - margin;
 var endy = canvas.clientHeight - margin;

 xoutput.innerHTML = endx;
 youtput.innerHTML = endy-margin;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   context.beginPath(); 

   context.moveTo(startx,starty);
   context.lineTo(endx,starty);
 context.lineTo(endx,endy);
  context.lineTo(startx,endy);
   context.lineTo(startx,starty);
  
  context.stroke();
 }
} //end of draw
```

```css
#bodySim {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<p id="X">X:</p>
<p id="Y">Y:</p>
<!--<form>
Timeline Item: <input type="text" name="item"><br>
Timeline Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
</form>-->
<div id="bodySim">
<canvas id="DemoCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: So this improved matters -- I now have a box. So it appears canvas is having a problem understanding what "100%" means. The box is now really tiny.

Comment: % and canvas doesn't play well together in almost any circumstance unless you make some corrections, i updated my answer to include a easy fix that uses the css vh (view-height) & vw (view-width) instead.